# Pregenerated localized python email templates

Tags: python, email, localization

I'm working on a simple python based system that sends a verification email to users.

We have users from all over the planet, thus would like to use a localized email template.

What is the pythonic approach to do this?

I thought about just having each email template in a separate file, and load it up based on the localized request, buuuuuuuuut I want to find out if there is a mo betta approach (or even more ideally a lib that I can just make use of).

Comment: Without knowing more about your system, this sounds fine to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to checkout the gettext module for handling language translations of bits of text if you have very complex templates: that would be the Pythonic solution there.

http://docs.python.org/library/gettext.html

You might also want to check out the locale module.

http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/locale/

http://docs.python.org/dev/library/locale.html

Comment: Thanks. The locale modules won't help (I think) because the locale will be the server's locale. I'd have the api that starts the email request, also take an optional locale parameter.